# How do you find all minimal vertex cover of bipartite graph $G$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with vertex set $V=V_1 \cup V_2$.
If $\mid V_1\mid= n$ and $\mid V_2\mid=m$ with $m\leq n$, then how to find all minimal vertex cover?

Comment: Minimal vertex covers can be computed easily from maximal matchings (for bipartite graphs). This [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8179&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives a method to enumerate all maximal matchings.

Comment: Thank you so much for the paper.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely dependent from bipartite graph to bipartite graph, [Konig's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)#Statement_of_the_theorem) states that the size of the minimal vertex cover is the size of the maximal matching. In your case, the largest matching can be at most $m$. Also see [Hall's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your help.